# How to make time to event in unbalanced panel data in r?

Tags: r

I have unbalanced panel data with a binary variable indicating if the event occurred or not. I want to control for time dependency. The way to do this is to control for the time it that had elapsed since the event has occured before.

Here is a reproducible example, with a vector of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

```
   id year onset time_since_event
1   1 1989     0                0
2   1 1990     0                1
3   1 1991     1                2
4   1 1992     0                0
5   1 1993     0                1
6   1 1994     0                2  
7   2 1989     0                0
8   2 1990     1                1
9   2 1991     0                0
10  2 1992     1                1
11  2 1993     0                2
12  2 1994     0                3  
13  3 1991     0                0
14  3 1992     0                1
15  3 1993     0                2
```

˚

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
year <- c(1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1991,1992,1993)
onset <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
time_since_event<-c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2) #what I want to create
df <- data.frame(cbind(id, year, onset,time_since_event))
```

Comment: Is "time_since_event" only linked with "onset"? Or did you intend to also have it linked with "id" or "year"?

Comment: Its linkted to both id and year since when the ID switched, I don't want the time_since_event to keep accumulating, it needs to be set back to 0

Comment: That is not demonstrated in your example, is it? Can you please update with that requirement and desired output?

Comment: Fixed! sorry about that

Comment: You never need to do `data.frame(cbind(...))`; try just `data.frame(...)`. This will also protect you against weird behavior when you have mixed data types (like a string ID or a date column).

Comment: I think your fix introduced a new mistake in the sample data for "onset". Also, what would "time_since_event" be if  the first value of offset for a given id is "1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
year <- c(1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1989,1990,1991,1992,1991,1992)
onset <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0)
period <- c(0, cumsum(onset)[-length(onset)])
time_since_event <- ave(year, id, period, FUN=function(x) x-x[1])
df <- data.frame(id, year, onset, time_since_event)
```

I created a variable called `period` which describes the different periods until each event.  It doesn't matter that the periods overlap patients, since we're going to group by patient and by period, so the count will start over if it's a new patient or a new period.

Using the `ave()` function allows us to assign values within each grouping.  Here we're analyzing `year` based on the grouping variables `id` and `period`.  The function I used at the end just subtracts the first value from the current value within each grouping.